# Defining polygon coordinates with a predefined image and plotting in R

Tags: r, plot, spatial

Here is what I need: I have an image and want to plot on specific rectangle-shaped parts of it (e.g., imagine having a picture of a chessboard and wanting to fill every square with a different color). I would like to be able to easily specify the coordinates for these parts and take these coordinates into R for plotting.

I don't have any experience with making such plots. I've thought of simply inserting an image into a plot with rasterImage (), then plotting with polygon (), but the task of setting up the coordinates for the polygon function seemed too time consuming - hence the question above.

If you have any better ideas than using a set of coordinates for the polygon function, please share. Any leads or packages suggestions would also be helpful.

thank you. Marko.

Comment: Post a dataset and what you might have tried. Asking us to do the spade work of constructing the example is unreasonable. Sometimes it's trivial but other times there are features that are unclear. You will short-circuit a lot of questions by posting data.

Comment: ok - that will take me some time as I've just started dealing with the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of trying to code the plot, I've made a rough drawing of how it should look like [(link here)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2gjab9uce2pwkz5/blueprintHeatmap.png). This is a blueprint of a retail store and I want to color the shelves based on the percentage of people who visited them. I will define the specific coloring later (probably using the RColorBrewer package), but now the problem is how do I tell R what to color, i.e., how do I define where the shelves are?

Comment: The grid package lets you stick rectangles in plots with choice of how they are located and oriented. You still haven't posted a dataset.

Comment: Here is [the data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ue609xlmpq0dnb2/data.csv) - the first column contains the shelf name, the second percentages of people who visited the shelf. [Here is just the blueprint](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yy6tpuj7ozq0had/blueprint.png), and [here a rough example of how it should look like in the end](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2gjab9uce2pwkz5/blueprintHeatmap.png). The problem is how to designate the shelf locations so that I don't have to type out the x-y locations myself, or if that is the only way, how can I specify the locations using pixels, not the axes scales in R.

Comment: Keep in mind that the colors in the example do not fit the data. And thank you for the help!

Comment: If you are going to position items in a grid, then each row needs an X, a Y, Height, Width, and a Rotation value, (with the color to be determined by the percentages). You can't seriously expect us unpaid volunteers to record positions from a picture for you, do you?

Comment: Not at all, and I hope I didn't leave that impression. I am looking for advice on how to do it in an easier way. If the only way to go is by specifying the coordinates, then I just have to do the shoveling. Still, do you have any advice on how to specify the coordinates precisely (i.e., so they cover the exact area they have to) without too much fiddling with the numbers?

Comment: I would be doing it with the grid functions, in particular `grid.rect`, so `help(package="grid")`

Comment: and if there were a lot of objects to draw (e.g. a hundred) - is there a way to speed up this process (e.g., to use an external program to specify the areas with the mouse)? And thank you for the suggestion, grid.rect() seems easier to use than rect() or polygon().

Comment: There is a `locator` function in base graphics, and a `grid.locator` in grid graphics.